# Creating an application print queue from PHP to Delphi

Tags: php, delphi, printing, ms-word, delphi-xe

I'm busy rewriting a pledge management system for a client in PHP. It basically stores donor, fundraiser, document, and pledge information in a database.

Upon the submission of each pledge, I need it to print two invoices, and any required documentation that the user may select.

In a normal situation, I'd get PHP (it's on a local server on Windows, by the way) to open Word, open the document, replace the variables, save, and print. However, one can't see how far along in that procedure is when using PHP.

So, I'd like to write an app in Delphi XE that handles this for me, and shows progress in a little popup, by means of an automated print queue. The PHP app, upon successfully inserting the data into the database, should run the Delphi app that would then print the documents. PHP would only need to send the required information in JSON or CSV format to the app.

Here's the problematic part for me: How can I get this data into a queue of some sort? I have considered ensuring the Delphi app is open at all times, and using a text file as a queue (with line feeds for each job), but I don't know how to fully implement it in such a way that it recognises it as a live queue. For example, if the app is currently printing, how do I get it to see that another item has been added to the queue at the same time?

Alternatively, perhaps there is a better way to do the queue management?

Comment: Overly broad question IMHO. You can use sockets, making your Delphi application a server and easily connecting to it from your php script to _manage_ the _queue_.

Comment: I'm really trying to get to the actual methodology of creating and managing the queue.

Comment: There's plenty of options, as usual, the first answer is: _it depends_!. How robust it have to be? What's your budget? Is it operating 24/7? what if the Delphi application is not running, or, in other words, does it need to be asynchronous? is it acceptable to loose the queue elements if the Delphi application crash?

Comment: The app will launch with Windows, always on standby, waiting for the queue to gain a new entry so that it may take action. Can't afford to loose entries. I'm having a look at @mjn's solution, which sounds about right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a message queue like [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/), [Apollo](http://activemq.apache.org/apollo/), [HornetQ](http://www.hornetq.org/) or [RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com/). There are (open source and commercial) libraries for Delphi available which allow to exchange messages over message queues.

The PHP app would send documents (text or binary data) to a message queue, for example `/queue/new_pledge`. The message is stored on the (ActiveMQ / HornetQ / RabbitMQ) message broker and waits there until the Delphi client connects. If the Delphi app connectes, it fetches all pending messages, similar to reading new email in a mail application. 
Sender and the client do not have to run at the same time (asynchronous operation).

This solution also supports load balancing: if more documents are received than can be handled by a single Delphi application, simply start additional instances on more computers. The messages in the queue will then be distributed between all Delphi apps.

For the PHP side, there are message broker client libraries which use a simple protocol called STOMP which is supported by these open source message brokers.

(I am the author of the [Habari Client](http://www.habarisoft.com/) STOMP libraries for Delphi and Free Pascal, wich support five different message brokers)

---

p.s. there is also a message queue system already in the operating system: [Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing).

Comment: This looks interesting - I'll be sure to have a look at those. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there no simpler framework that can be used to manage this kind of thing? These apps do look great, and I'm sure they will help, but my applications are very small, and I would not want to depend on complex pieces of software. Is there not a simple, small platform that can be used? If there isn't, I will dig into one of these, as well as your client. Oh, and I am not entirely familiar with MSMQ - how would I be able to create a simple queuing mechanism with that?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple

Post the information from PHP using `json_encode()` to Indy httpserver [Indy 10 Http Server sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131093/indy-10-http-server-sample)

Use the advantages of the HTTP protocol and not reinvent the wheel.

Use this single Unit to read JSON in Delphi http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/

Comment: HTTP is only the transport protocol, it does not provide any message queueing logic and uses a synchronous communication model (request/response). To provide typical [message queue features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue#Usage), the Delphi message broker app would have to implement more than just the protocol. In other words, reinventing the missing other three wheels of the car ... :)

Comment: The advantage of keeping simplest is by this way you are using a minimum of non native components. If you need to upgrade to a future version of Delphi or to migrate to Lazarus prepare yourself to cry and search for this bunch of components for the new platform. While implement this FIFO it's a simple job http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896666/how-do-you-design-fifo-queue-with-variable-data-size